# java.lang.NullPointerException: null in spring mvc & thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am persisting a player to a team (One to Many = team->player) via the players log in entity (player -> userlogin is a one to one relationship), I am getting a null pointer exception and I cant seem to figure out why its returning null.

I think my team is returning null which may have something to do with the way i am using thymeleaf on the html page.

Heres the error im getting

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.FYP.Club.model.Team.addPlayer(Team.java:168) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.FYP.Club.controller.HomeController.joinTeam(HomeController.java:126) ~[classes/:na]
```

Note that line 126 = team.addPlayer(player); in the below controller:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {


      @Autowired
        UserLoginRepository userRepository;

      @Autowired
            TeamRepository teamRepository;

      @Autowired
        GameRepository gameRepository;

      @Autowired
            LeagueRepository leagueRepository;

      @Autowired
            PlayerRepository playerRepository;

     @Autowired
        ManagerRepository managerRepository;

     @Autowired
        PhysioRepository physioRepository;

     @Autowired
        CoachingStaffRepository coachingStaffRepository;

   @RequestMapping(value="/jointeam", method=RequestMethod.POST)
   public String joinTeam(@Valid Team team, Principal principal)
   {

= (SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()).getName();

       Authentication loggedInUser = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
       String email = loggedInUser.getName();



       Long id = (userRepository.findByEmail(email)).getId();


       Player player = playerRepository.findByLoginId(id);

       if (player != null)
       {
           team.addPlayer(player);

           teamRepository.save(team);
       }
       else 
       {
           return "parseGame";
       }

               return "parseGame";
   }
```

My team entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "team")

public class Team implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String teamName;
    private int leaguePosition;
    public String teamAddress;
    public String level;

    @OneToOne
    private Manager manager;

    @OneToOne
    private Physio physio;


    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
     public Set<CoachingStaff> coachingStaff;


    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
     public Set<Player> players;

    public Team() {

    }

    public Team(Long id, String teamName, int leaguePosition) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.teamName = teamName;
        this.leaguePosition = leaguePosition;
    }



    public Team(Long id, String teamName, int leaguePosition, Manager manager) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.teamName = teamName;
        this.leaguePosition = leaguePosition;
        this.manager = manager;
    }



    public Team(Long id, String teamName, int leaguePosition, Manager manager,
            Physio physio) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.teamName = teamName;
        this.leaguePosition = leaguePosition;
        this.manager = manager;
        this.physio = physio;
    }



    public Team(Long id, String teamName, int leaguePosition,
            String teamAddress, String level, Manager manager, Physio physio,
            Set<CoachingStaff> coachingStaff, Set<Player> players) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.teamName = teamName;
        this.leaguePosition = leaguePosition;
        this.teamAddress = teamAddress;
        this.level = level;
        this.manager = manager;
        this.physio = physio;
        this.coachingStaff = coachingStaff;
        this.players = players;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTeamName() {
        return teamName;
    }

    public void setTeamName(String teamName) {
        this.teamName = teamName;
    }

    public int getLeaguePosition() {
        return leaguePosition;
    }

    public void setLeaguePosition(int leaguePosition) {
        this.leaguePosition = leaguePosition;
    }

    public Set<Player> getPlayers() {
        return players;
    }

    public void setPlayers(Set<Player> players) {
        this.players = players;
    }

    public Set<CoachingStaff> getCoachingStaff() {
        return coachingStaff;
    }

    public void setCoachingStaff(Set<CoachingStaff> coachingStaff) {
        this.coachingStaff = coachingStaff;
    }

    public Manager getManager() {
        return manager;
    }

    public void setManager(Manager manager) {
        this.manager = manager;
    }

    public Physio getPhysio() {
        return physio;
    }

    public void setPhysio(Physio physio) {
        this.physio = physio;
    }

    public String getTeamAddress() {
        return teamAddress;
    }

    public void setTeamAddress(String teamAddress) {
        this.teamAddress = teamAddress;
    }

    public String getLevel() {
        return level;
    }

    public void setLevel(String level) {
        this.level = level;
    }

    public void addPlayer(Player player){
        players.add(player);
    }


}
```

My webpage that uses thymeleaf:

```
th:each="team : ${teams}"
 th:text="${team.teamName}"
 th:text="${team.teamAddress}"
 th:text="${team.level}"
     th:text="${team.manager}"></td>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">View Team</button>  

         th:action="@{/jointeam}" method="post" th:object="${team}"

        <button onclick="myFunction()">Join Team</button>
```

My logic is that for each team object that is displayed theres a button beside it saying "join" which will pass that particular team object into the /jointeam method in the controller, but I am unsure if this is the cause of the null pointer exception.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't the team variable that's null?

Comment: I am not sure at all @KleoG, all i know is its not player as it is able to get through this if statement:
 if (player != null)
       {
        team.addPlayer(player);

           teamRepository.save(team);
       }

Comment: Okay, so, I'm assuming you're using an IDE, if you can put a break-point on that line that breaks, and check for the value that "team" is (you can find how to do this online depending on your IDE). If it is not player that's not null, the only other thing that can be null, is team.

Comment: thanks @KleoG but it seems I can not figure out how to display the value of the variables when debugging

Comment: If you are using netbeans, hover over the variable and it should show, with intellij there should be a debug window at the bottom of the screen, im not sure with eclipse you may have to find that online. If all else fails, follow your code and see where team is coming from (where joinTeam method is being called from) to identify what team is being passed in as.

Comment: @KleoG I was able to figure it out on eclipse and all the objects/variables are not null?

Comment: Okay, all i can assume is that the Set 'players' which is in Team is not being initialised (the right constructor isnt being called), as not all of the constructors initialise that Set. I think its a knock on effect with that and it's actually the entire set which is null and cannot be added to.

Comment: I dropped the database and started over again ensuring theres one blank constructor and a constructor with all the variables, this resulted in the same issue. But your suspicion seemed to be on the right track @KleoG

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163355/discussion-between-kleo-g-and-gavin-james-beere).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When having a JPA @OneToMany mapping I suggest to always use lazy initialization for the collection on the getter:

```
public Set<Player> getPlayers() {
    if (players == null)
        players = new HashSet<>();
    return players;
}
```

Then add Player through the getter:

```
public void addPlayer(Player player){
    getPlayers().add(player);
}
```

That way you avoid NPE.